# MySql: 4 dimensions in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing the following problem I can't solve. I have one table called "tbl_products" which contains a list of products with the following attributes:

1. Country (1 country)
2. Category (3 categories)
3. Price Range (2 Price Ranges)
4. Date (the date the product was sold)

Now I want to construct the following table

columns: Date
rows: Country, Category, Price Range

The columns are labeled per month
THe rows should have the following hierachy

1.Country1

1.1 Cat1

1.1.1 Price1

1.1.2 Price2

1.2 Cat2

1.2.1 Price1

1.2.2 Price2

1.3 Cat3

1.3.1 Price1

1.3.2 Price2

How would I construct the SQL query to get this information? The cells of the table consist of a count() [#products sold].

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is essentially a tree, and a heterogenous one. This is not something you can easily get from an SQL query. What relational algebra loows you to really get is something like this:

```
country cat price
     US   1  2.39
     US   1  3.19
     US   2  7.49
...
     UK  99  2.80
```

This trick is that you order by country first, by category next, by price last. When you read the data, you track the current value of each column. Once `cat` has changed, it's time to print a new 'Category ...' heading; once `country` has changed, it's time to print a new 'Country ...' heading.

So, the query will be something like

```
select country, cat, price -- and whatever else
from tbl_products
where ... -- add any limiting clauses, or omit
order by country, cat, price;
```

Hope this helps.